# What is the formal name of this matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, tensor-products, kronecker-product

Given two $m\times n$ matrices, I want to calculate the sum of the inner product of every pair of rows (or columns) in the two matrices, therefore the result is a real number. This matrix operation looks like below
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{array}\right)(\times)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1n}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & b_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
b_{m1} & b_{m2} & \cdots & b_{mn}
\end{array}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m\langle \boldsymbol{a_i}, \boldsymbol{b_j}\rangle$$

I want to know the formal name of this matrix product. I have looked up the definitions of [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product), but this is neither. The value falls between the Frobenius inner product and the sum of the Kronecker product.

Comment: @BenGrossmann No this is not the Frobenius inner product. I have confirmed it using Numpy. For example, the $a_{11}b_{21}$ term (when calculating the inner product between the first row of $A$ and second row of $B$) is not summed in the Frobenius inner product. Frobenius inner product strictly sums $a_{mn}b_{mn}$

Comment: I misread the sum, you're right

Comment: If $e$ denotes the column vector $e = (1,1,\dots,1)$, then we can write this sum as 
$$
A (\times) B = e^TAB^Te = \operatorname{tr}(AB^Tee^T).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Consider the product of columns
$$\eqalign{
A\;(\times)\;B &= \sum_i\sum_j a_i:b_j \\
 &= \sum_i\sum_j \LR{Ae_i}:\LR{Be_j} \\
 &= A:B\LR{\sum_i\sum_j e_je_i^T} \\
 &= A:BJ \\
 &= \trace{A^TBJ} \\
}$$
Here $\{e_k\}$ are the standard basis vectors, $J$ the all-ones matrix, and the symbol $(:)$ denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Similarly the product of rows would be
$$\trace{AB^TJ}$$